# Reason behind the "index outside bound of arrays" error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, hash, webforms

I wrote a code that retrieves the hashed password from database and compares it with the password in the Login Form.

```
                if (usercheck.HasRows)
                {
                    while (usercheck.Read())
                    {
                        string hashst = usercheck.GetValue(1).ToString();

                        byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashst);

                        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
                        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);

                        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passsign.Text, salt, 100000);
                        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);

                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                            if (hashBytes[i + 16] != hash[i])
                            {
                                lblUsPsav.Text = "Incorrect Password";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("./Profile.aspx"));
                            }
```

However, the error says "Index was outside the bound of errays" on the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

I cannot know the reason why.
Code works perfectly on the contrary, concerning the data retrieval and anything else.

Comment: Are you sure to have at least 36 bytes in the hashBytes array? Debug your program to discover it.

Comment: no it doesn't, it has 16 bytes

Comment: So, i+16 is out of range if i = 1

Comment: why `i < 20` and `hashBytes[i + 16]` can you explain

Comment: so should it be (hashbytes[16] != hash[i]) ?

Comment: It doens't have sense. Why compare always the same byte (16) with hash[i]?. Perhaps you need _hashbytes[i] != hash[i]_. But at this point I suggest you to show also the code that encrypt the data to be stored in the database. Some things are not clear in your question

Comment: I figured it out, I compared the hash in the login form with a different type of stored data, i kind of missed it out but thank you for responding. If i didn't face these mistakes I won't learn